# Apache URL rewrite

Tags: apache, symfony, url-rewriting

I can access my php symfony 2 app urls as follows:

```
http://localhost/jba/php/web/app_dev.php/login
```

I'd like to make it shorter, so that when browser requests

```
http://localhost/login
```

it shows the original page. I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ jba/php/web/app_dev.php/$1
```

but it didn't work (just says "not found"). Rewrite log says:

```
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /login
(1) pass through /login
```

What is the correct RewriteRule for that?

Comment: Have you considered making a vhost with the DocumentRoot set to jba/php/web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and let me know if it works for you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ jba/php/web/app_dev.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: It worked for login, but then for next page "http://localhost/a/menu" again "not found" error thrown. Also, my css and js files are not loading; they are inside /var/www/html/jba/php/web/static folder.

Comment: **Typically** you have to create re-writes for certain ones that you want. One URL rewrite doesn't always fix every scenario. You can have as many as you like to make your site work how you want. Where is "localhost/a/menu" suppose to point to?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /jba/php/web/app_dev.php/$1
```